# Filetransfer in remoting

Tags: c#, .net, remoting

I'm new to .net remoting,i done few sample applications on .net remoting.i can easily
get a file from the server through the remote object but i dont know how to send a file to the server side ,if it is possible through a interface means how to design it.give me some suggestions and links ,it will be useful for me to drive in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a file, you could repeatedly call a method on the server to give it the file chunk by chunk. Like this:

```
static int CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;

// open the file
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("path\to\file");

// send by chunks
byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
int numBytesRead = CHUNK_SIZE;
while ((numBytesRead = stream.Read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    // resize the array if we read less than requested
    if (numBytesRead < CHUNK_SIZE)
        Array.Resize(data, numBytesRead);

    // pass the chunk to the server
    server.GiveNextChunk(data);
    // re-init the array so it's back to the original size and cleared out.
    data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
}

// an example of how to let the server know the file is done so it can close
// the receiving stream on its end.
server.GiveNextChunk(null);

// close our stream too
stream.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You must implement this behavior.  The client reads the file and sends the bytes.  The server receives the bytes and writes the file.  There is more to it, but that is the basics of what you will need to do.